# Should models representing a single row return data generated using multiple rows?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, orm, model

**Some background:**

- This is for an MVC application built without using any frameworks, but follows the MVC paradigm.
- I am using an ORM library called [RedBean](http://www.redbeanphp.com/) to talk to the database.
- While RedBean represents data using "beans", it supports wrapping them into a model, so custom functions may be provided by the model:

  ```
  $account = R::dispense('account');
  $account->name = "john";
  R::store($account);
  $account->getFormattedLastUpdatedTime('America/New_York');
  ```

**Now the question:**

Currently, each instance of the model would represent 1 row in the database. If I have a collection of accounts, then I would have an array of "account" models.

In the application, I have a feature for custom profile fields (don't worry, I am not using EAV though :)). One of the tables stores metadata for those fields (name, description etc) for generating the form fields for those custom profile fields. Once again, each row of the metadata represents 1 form field and each row is represented by 1 model.

I now wish to write a method to convert all those rows into a form object which can then be used for rendering and processing the form. But, where should this method live? My initial thought was to place it in the model representing the custom profile field metadata.

Clarification: This function would not be in the `account` model, but instead in the `profile_fields_meta` model.

**Problem**

As each model should represent 1 row, it seems a bit "dirty" to have the model return an object that would be generated from MULTIPLE rows in the database. Am I correct to say this is not the best way to do it? What do you recommend I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

It would be right to have extended ArrayObject (http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) or other container class to run methods for collection.
Try to modify query methods to return data in your custom collection class instead of array if specified.

Comment: In collection you can store additional metadata for your object and then just pass the whole collection to a form constructor method.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherent to MVC that says "each model [instance] should represent one row." Often in MVC frameworks the model (as seen by the controller, at least) is entirely ignorant of the data store and doesn't have any concept of or direct mapping to a "row." This isn't necessarily the case with ORMs but a model needn't adhere to an ORM's constraints.

However, though it's hard to tell without knowing more about your schema and implementation, the functionality you're describing doesn't sound appropriate for your Account model. In fact, it sounds to me like you should consider having a "FormField" model such that, in Rails parlance, Account "has many" FormFields.

And for the record, EAV isn't always bad, it's just often misused.

Comment: I have added some clarification, the method for form generation would not live in the `account` model, but in an `profile_fields_meta` model. However, as each model also represents CRUD to each row, is this method appropriate in the model?